# rich:progressBar and a4j:status

Tags: richfaces, progress-bar, status, ajax4jsf

i have an "a4j:status" which indicates ajax activity in my application. On one page i have an "rich:progressBar" which updates once per second. How can i avoid that my a4j:status is shown when the progressbar updates?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your "rich:progressBar" inside of a "a4j:region".

The "a4j:status" will only show the progress of it's parent "a4j:region".